# Filtering with term on tag key with a value containing a dot do not return any result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 5.2

My query is:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "tag": "server-dev.user-log" }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can filter with a tag value like `abcd` but it seems I cannot with `ab.cd`

I guess this is because of the Tokenizer. Is there a way to say like strict equivalence? or if it comes from the `.` to escape it?

The tag mapping is:

```
"tag": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Have you set a mapping on your index?

Comment: can you show your schema settings and mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've been able to make it work like:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "terms":  { "tag": ["server", "dev.user", "log"] }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It seems the `-` is a token delimiter

I just want to add that my configuration is very standard. I didn't modify the mapping. The mapping is created by fluentd.

=======> EDIT <=======

If you replace `tag` by `tag.keyword` you don't need to do the above solution anymore (which btw do not work with any value)

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "tag.keyword": "server-dev.user-log" }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a [Standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for your field tag, and for a token `server-dev.user-log`, following tokens will be provided:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "server",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "dev.user",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "log",
            "start_offset": 16,
            "end_offset": 19,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

and, that's the reason, you do not have match, so things that should fix it, is to add [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) for a field tag, with tokenizer which will preserve whole token. The simplest choice is [KeywordAnalyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), with settings for an index like this:

```
{
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
          "properties": {
            "text": {
              "type": "tag",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the post with `tag` mapping, it seems to already be of type `keyword`